# How to make a 3d surface plot with matplotlib, Z is not calculated by func?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geometry-surface

I have 3 rows data used as X,Z, Y separately. But Z data is directly read from a csv file, so it's not a function of (x,y).

The data shows:

```
[[0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e-01 2.00000000e-01 3.00000000e-01
  3.09958506e-01 3.20000000e-01 3.25000000e-01 3.50000000e-01
  3.75000000e-01 4.00000000e-01 5.00000000e-01 6.00000000e-01
  7.00000000e-01]
 [1.31722083e+06 1.31722083e+06 1.31722083e+06 1.31722089e+06
  1.31722121e+06 1.31722083e+06 1.31722098e+06 1.31722134e+06
  1.31722101e+06 1.31722083e+06 1.31738292e+06 3.92708000e+12
  7.93453000e+12]
 [1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02
  1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02
  1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02 1.42000000e+02
  1.42000000e+02]]
```

I referred this answer:
[Simplest way to plot 3d surface given 3d points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423601/simplest-way-to-plot-3d-surface-given-3d-points)

And my code is:

```
mat = pd.read_csv('results2.csv', header=None,sep=',').values
mat = mat[0:3,:13]
#print(mat)

Sparsity1 = mat[0,:]
agents1 = mat[2,:]
optimal1 = mat[1,:]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax = Axes3D(fig)
#ax.plot_surface(Sparsity1,agents1, optimal1, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis)
ax.plot_trisurf(Sparsity1, agents1, optimal1, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(Sparsity1, agents1, optimal1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf)
plt.show()
```

How can I make 3d plot with surface?
It always tells me:

```
RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.
```

If I use np.meshgrid(x,y), then I got the error:

```
 ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional”
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code crashes is that your input data is degenerate.
The `plot_trisurf` function tries to construct a [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) from the `X`, `Y` parameters of the function (in your code these are `Sparsity1, agents1`). However, `agents1` holds identical values so you are trying to triangulate a set of points on a line (a singular/degenerate configuration), which invokes the `singular input data` error from [QHull](http://www.qhull.org/), the underlying library that scipy uses.

If you call the function with the `agents1` as your `Z` values (instead of as your `Y` values) you will get a surface plot without the error.

`ax.plot_trisurf(Sparsity1, optimal1, agents1, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)`.

Alternatively you can construct your own triangular mesh and pass it to the function, like what was done in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589080/9702190).