# Unable to make 3d Plots with legend for dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to make a 3d plot from a `Pandas.DataFrame` object.

**Requirements**

- The number of columns to be plotted for `z` may vary and hence I am using a loop for the `z` values with a fixed `x` and `y` values. The code is shown in `Code 1`.

**Code 1**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib, base64
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

column_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for x in df.columns:
    if(x!='A' and x!='B'):
      ax2.plot_surface(df['A'].values, df['B'].values, df[x].values, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
      ax2.legend()
```

**Problem:**

When I execute `Code 1`, I get an error -

```
Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

I have solved it when i used - `plot_trisurf`, as shown in `Code 2`.

**Code 2**

```
for x in df.columns:
    if(x!='A' and x!='B'):
      ax2.plot_trisurf(df['A'].values, df['B'].values, df[x].values, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
      ax2.legend()
```

But now I am getting a different error -

```
Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.
```

**Question**

- How can I make 3d plots for a `Pandas.DataFrame` with different number of columns for Z **with Legend**

**Note**

The data provided above is just for experimentation and may not be uniform and can have decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The qhull error you're getting is probably because your `'A'` and `'B'` columns contain data that is linearly dependent, i.e., the points are geometrically on a line (you did not post the data so I cannot verify this). The `plot_trisurf` function tries to construct a [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) from the `X, Y` parameters you pass it (the `df['A'].values`, `df['B'].values` in your code).
A singular/degenerate configuration invokes the error from [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/), which is the underlying library that is used to construct the Delaunay triangulation (see also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011816/9702190)).

If your data is singular/degenerate you can use [scatter plots](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) or [line plots](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#line-plots) instead.

If you insist on a surface plot, and your data is singular, you might try to ["joggle"](http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-impre.htm#injoggle) the `X, Y` data so the underlying triangulation will not fail.