# How to use matplotlib to plot a triangle mesh cuboids?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to implement a cuboid and expressed it by triangle mesh. It is easy to implement a surface of a cuboid so that I wanted to try to implement the cuboid by creating six surfaces and merge them together. However, when I tried to draw a mesh surface that is vertical to the ground there is an error I can not understand:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.random.rand(20)
y = [0] * 20
z =np.random.rand(20)

ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
plt.show()


RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.
```

If I switch the value of y and z it can work properly and draw a surface which is parallel to the ground.

Answer (score 1):

The call to the `plot_trisurf(x, y, z)` function computes a *2D* [Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) from the `x, y` parameters and sets the `z` coordinate of the triangles to the corresponding `z` parameter.
This may be a bit misleading since you pass three coordinate arrays `x, y, z` and therefore might expect them to be considered in the same way, which they are not.

The reason your code crashes is that your `x, y` input data is in a degenerate configuration - all the `x,y` points are on the line `y=0`. This causes the underlying triangulation computation to fail - see my previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011816/9702190) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64032601/9702190) for further explanation.