# 3D Density visualisation with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to plot a 3D column with associated density. 
Specifically, I have a `.txt` file with 4 separate columns `x, y, z, density`. The first 3 columns are the cartesian coordinates of the column, density a list of density values associated with each cross-section, at height z, of the column.

I can plot the column with a colormap as follows

```
 x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
 z=np.linspace(-20, 5, 50)
 Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
 Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)

 # Draw parameters
 rstride = 1
 cstride = 1
 surf1 = ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=1., rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride,antialiased=False, cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0)
 surf2 = ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=1., rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride, antialiased=False, cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0)
```

and I can associate a colormap to z

```
fig.colorbar(surf1, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

I would like to associate the colormap to the values in the fourth column, while maintaining the plotted dimensions of the cylinder constant.

I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218543/colouring-the-surface-of-a-sphere-with-a-set-of-scalar-values-in-matplotlib) helps.