# How to plot an interpolated scalar field on a 3D triangulated surface in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, interpolation, mesh

My problem is as follows: I have a triangulated surface with arrays `X,Y,Z` containing the coordinates of the mesh vertices and array `Triangles` containing the indices of the vertex points for each corner of the triangle (i.e. each line of the array contains a triplet defining a triangle in terms of vertices). Furthermore, I have an array `Field` containing scalar field values on each vertex of the mesh. I wish to plot the triangular mesh in Python, where each triangle is colored according to the field values of its vertices.

I have found a solution for this problem, if one assigns a **single color per triangle** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218543/colouring-the-surface-of-a-sphere-with-a-set-of-scalar-values-in-matplotlib/24229480)). What if I want to **interpolate** the field values over the surface of each single triangle, so that there is a continuous (smooth even better) coloring of the mesh?

I thought to use the tri_api of Matplotlib, because it can also do interpolation over triangular grids, however I have not found a solution that suits my needs. [This demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/triinterp_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-triinterp-demo-py) comes close, but it is restricted on flat surfaces and interpolates on a rectangular grid.

Of course, the solution does not have to entail Matplotlib, it can be any other Python library/toolbox. I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Plotting in 3D is hard, and there are other software tools that you can use, notably [ParaView](http://paraview.org/). You'll first have to convert your mesh into a file that ParaView can use, though. To this end, you can for example use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (which I wrote):

```py
import numpy
import meshio

points = numpy.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    ])
cells = {
    "triangle": numpy.array([
        [0, 1, 2]
        ])
    }
meshio.write_points_cells(
    "foo.vtk",
    points,
    cells,
    point_data=point_data,
    )
```